# java protected method accessibility

Tags: java, oop

In the below code the Consumer class can access the protected method of Parent class.How is it possible since there is no relation between Parent and Consumer class.Please explain

```java
class Parent {
    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("PUBLIC METHOD");
    }
    private void method2(){
        System.out.println("PRIVATE METHOD");
    }
    protected void method3(){
        System.out.println("PROTECTED METHOD");
    }
}

public class Consumer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Parent parentObj = new Parent();
        parentObj.method1();
        //parentObj.method2();
        parentObj.method3();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This explains java member access: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`protected` means: same package or by inheritance. Since your classes are both in the `default package` (not recommended in real life), `protected` enables access. By the way: if you tried to test java access control, you forgot `default access` (`default access` = no modifier = `package private`).

`private` access on the other hand means: access from nowhere except this particular class (and non-static inner classes, which are still member of the host-class).

Comment: hi, can i call non static protected methods from inherited class's main statement?

Answer (score 8):

Here are the relevant excerpts from the Java Language Specification:

> ### [JLS 6.6 Access Control](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6)
>
> The Java programming language provides mechanisms for *access control*, to prevent the users of a `package` or `class` from depending on unnecessary details of the implementation of that `package` or `class`. If access is permitted, then the accessed entity is said to be *accessible*.
>
> #### [JLS 6.6.1 Determining Accessibility](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.1)
>
> - [...]
> - **A member/constructor of a reference type is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member/constructor is declared to permit access:**
>
>   - `public`: access is permitted.
>   - `protected`: **access is permitted only when one of the following is true**:
>
>     - **Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the** `package` **containing the class in which the** `protected` **member or constructor is declared.**
>     - Access is correct as described in [JLS 6.6.2 Details on `protected` Access](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2).
>
>       - A `protected` member/constructor of an object may be accessed from outside the `package` in which it is declared only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object.
>   - `private`: access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.
>   - Otherwise, we say there is *default access*, which is permitted only when the access occurs from within the `package` in which the type is declared.

The section in bold is the answer to the question in this scenario: `Parent` and `Consumer` belong to the same `package`, thus, at the very least, `protected` members of `Parent` are accessible from `Consumer`.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Controlling Access to Members of a Class](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 3):

Due to package protection.

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/packagescope.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, they're in the same package.  Secondly, Consumer is an inner class of Parent.

Comment: @adam was my first thought too

Comment: @Adam .... Why cant I access the private methods even though Consumer is in same package?

Comment: @javauser look at my post for explanation

Comment: @JavaUser: Because that's what private means.  Private members are only accessible inside the same class (and by implication, in nested classes).  David Hall's comment had a good reference you should look at: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1):

Adam you are right!
They are in the same package thats why consumer class is able to access protected method of parent class. Consumer is not an inner class of parent.