# Restricted access on method call using Java polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, protected

I have some scenario like this:

```
public class BaseClass {
    protected void protectedMethod(OtherObject object) {
    ...
    }
} 

public class Child1 extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    protected void protectedMethod(OtherObject object) {
        super.protectedMethod(object);
        // Custom Child1 logic
        ...
    }
}

public class Child2 extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    protected void protectedMethod(OtherObject object) {
        super.protectedMethod(object);
        // Custom Child2 logic
        ...
    }
}
```

Then when i call the "protectedMethod" iterating through an array of "BaseClass" object, compiler gives me protected access error:

```
OtherObject other = new OtherObject();

BaseClass[] objects = {
    new Child1(),
    new Child2()
}

for (BaseClass object : objects) {
    object.protectedMethod(other); //this line gives me protected access error
}
```

But if i do the same in a different not polymorphism manner, it works fine.

```
OtherObject other = new OtherObject();

Child1 child1 = new Child1();
Child2 child2 = new Child2();

child1.protectedAccess(other);
child2.protectedAccess(other);
```

I don't get to tell what is the difference between the two ways.

Comment: Are the two child classes in the same package as the test program by any chance?

Comment: Where are you invoking the method from??

Comment: The difference is, in the second one you execute different methods (from classes Child1 and Child2) but in the first one you execute BaseClass's method twice....

Maybe you want to make BaseClass (or the protectedMethod) abstract?

Comment: You're calling a different method in every scenario.  Sometimes you're calling `protectedMethod()`, other times `protectedMethod(other)`, and even `protectedAccess(other)`.  Do you mean for these to all be the same?

Comment: @Shark i can't modify base class because it comes from an external dependency, maybe the creators of it did this for some reason, but i can't seem to find out that reason.

Comment: Then that's the case, because `protected` also allows access from within the same package.

Comment: @Vulcan i actually mean what you said, fixed in the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, the ''protected'' access qualifier allows access not only by subclasses, but by other classes in the same package.

If your last code snippet is in the same package as Child1 and Child2, then it would have access to the protected methods in Child1 and Child2.

**EDIT:**

You can fix this problem and keep your polymorphism by introducing your own base class, in your own package.

```
 public MyBaseClass extends BaseClass { 
    @Override
    protected void protectedMethod(OtherObject object) {
        super.protectedMethod(object);
    }
 }

 public Child1 extends MyBaseClass { ... }
 public Child2 extends MyBaseClass { ... }
```

And then work with a collection of your own base class type.

```
 NyBaseClass[] objects = {
    new Child1(),
    new Child2()
 }

 for (MyBaseClass object : objects) {
    object.protectedMethod(other); 
 }
```

Comment: Ok, but why it still don't compile in first scenario? Is there a way to modify first scenario to make it work without modifying Baseclass?

Comment: Likely Baseclass is in a different package than Child1, Child2 and the calling code. You could make it work by making your own base class extending Baseclass, and putting it in the same package. That is, Baseclass<--MyBaseClass<--(Child1,Child2).

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables and Methods with protected modifier is only accessible `either in derived class` or in `other class in the same package`..

So, it might be possible that your `Base class` is in different package **pkg1**, and your `derived classes` and the `class` from where you are using the `protected method` are in the same package **pkg2**, `different` from the `base` class package `pkg1`..

Then by above property, you would be able to access the methods of derived class since they are in same package.. But, since `base class` is in different package, and also not the super class of your `test class`.. It cannot be accessed..

**EDIT** :- Ok, here is what you can do in case you cannot change your `Base Class`..

```
for (BaseClass object : objects) {
    if (object instanceof Child1) {
        ((Child1)object).protectedMethod(other);

    } else if(object instanceof Child2) {
        ((Child1)object).protectedMethod(other);
    }
}
```

But, that vanishes all polymorphic stuff from your problem... This is just a workaround..

Comment: Is there a way to modify first scenario to make it work without modifying Baseclass?

Comment: @Jams.. There is only one way, if you don't want to modify base class.. Move all classes into the same package.. Your problem will be solved..

Comment: I can't, cause BaseClass is from an external library

Comment: @Jams.. So, you can move your derived classes and the Test class from `package pkg2` to package `pkg1`.. You can change them right.. Define them under the same package that the base class is..

Comment: @Jams.. Ok wait.. What external library??

Comment: I could but it will break the order by adding a custom class in a dependency package, i guess i'm gonna have to stick with the second way.

Comment: it's from Orika, the class name is ConfigurableMapper

Comment: @Jams.. Or in the first case, inside for-loop, you can typecast your `base class` reference to appropriate `subclass` based on `instanceof` check..   SEE my edited post..

Comment: there isn't a way of perform a dynamic cast base on the subclass's class and therefore not using instanceof operator?

Answer (score 0):

I would check this entry:
[Java Protected Method Accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058976/java-protected-method-accessibility)

Protected is limited to the same package and children. If you need access to a method outside of the package, it should be public.